# Dynamically updating exports Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have this object that is being exported and imported by other files. Initially,  the object is empty but during an event change ( a button clicked), the object is filled with keys and values but still remains empty in the files that imported it. How can I dynamically update an object and then export it with it's new values.

The code looks something like this:

`firstFile.js`

```
const anObject = {};

function clicked() {

 anObject.firstName = "John";
 anObject.lastName = "Doe" ;

}

module.exports = anObject;
```

`secondFile.js`

```
const importedObject = require("./firstFile");

console.log(importedObject) // always returns an empty object
```

Comment: How you are calling the function `clicked`?

Comment: Don't really get your question. The function clicked() is used by an element in the html. Like `onClick="clicked()`

Comment: @AlfMoh If you are doing this in a browser with HTML and such you aren't using Node.js...

Comment: It's an Electron application

Comment: @AlfMoh I would specify that in your question and also add the fact that you are doing the onClick in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export and call the `clicked` function. Otherwise you are never actually updating that object.

For example.

`firstFile.js`

```
const anObject = {};

function clicked() {

 anObject.firstName = "John";
 anObject.lastName = "Doe" ;

}

module.exports = anObject;
module.exports.clicked = clicked;
```

`secondFile.js`

```
const importedObject = require("./firstFile");
console.log(importedObject.firstName) //undefined
importedObject.clicked()
console.log(importedObject.firstName) //John
```

**Edit**

After discussing further with the OP this is an Electron application. The code above works in Node.js. Electron might have a different setup and require extra steps to make this work.

Comment: @AlfMoh It should console.log `undefined` the first time then after calling `clicked()` it should console.log `John`. Is that not what is happening?

Comment: Nope, I have actually set a setInterval of 5secs to see if there will be changes but it keeps on  logging 'undefined'

Comment: @AlfMoh I just tested this. It works perfectly. Based on your comment in your question it looks like you aren't using Node.js. If that is the case your question is VERY misleading.

Comment: @AlfMoh What happens if you put a console.log in your clicked function? Is it even being called?

Comment: Yes, it is being called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161766/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-alf-moh).